# Git Bash failed to locate command, unable to set path appropriately

Tags: git, bash

I am trying to clone and install [civicrm-buildkit](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit) using Git bash.
After successfully cloning, I tried running command but got the following error:

```
Failed to locate command PHP.  
Please install it (and set path appropriately).
```

Can any please tell me how I can set the PHP command path?
(I am running on Windows 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`civicrm/civicrm-buildkit`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit) does list PHP as a prerequisite:

> PHP 5.3+ (For MAMP/XAMPP/etc, see [Setup Command-Line PHP](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Setup+Command-Line+PHP))

For Windows, you can follow [Command Line PHP on Microsoft Windows](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php) (after [installing php first](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.manual.php)):

> - Append the location of the PHP executable (`php.exe`, `php-win.exe` or `php-cli.exe` depending upon your PHP version and display preferences) to the `PATH` environment variable. Read more about how to add your PHP directory to PATH in the [corresponding FAQ entry](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.addtopath).
> - Append the `.PHP` extension to the `PATHEXT` environment variable. This can be done at the same time as amending the `PATH` environment variable. Follow the same steps as described in the [FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.addtopath) but amend the `PATHEXT` environment variable rather than the `PATH` environment variable.
> - Associate the `.PHP` extension with a file type.
>     This is done by running the following command:

```
    assoc .php=phpfile
```

> - Associate the `phpfile` file type with the appropriate PHP executable.
>     This is done by running the following command:

```
    ftype phpfile="C:\PHP5\php.exe" -f "%1" -- %~2
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to overcome this issue by setting the environmental path in windows advanced system settings. :)

Comment: @NatnaelGetachew Great! don't forget to take the tour (http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer